# mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError

Tags: angular, angular-material

HTML CODE

```
`<mat-form-field>
      <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" name="categoryImage" >
 </mat-form-field>`
```

TS code

```
onFileSelected(event){
console.log(event);}
```

getting error even before operation
mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.  at this 
 line getMatFormFieldMissingControlError

Comment: `<input matInput`. Next time read the documentation carefully : https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Comment: Input type "file" isn't supported by matInput. got this error after using matInput.

Comment: Then don't use a `mat-form-field`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<mat-form-field>` doesn't support `<input type="file" />` and as far as I can see there is nothing that supports it. Just remove the `mat-form-field` element entirely.

The form will still work without it.